# Select en Vuejs No me carga el arreglo de objetos

Tags: vue.js, select, axios

- Utilizo para este desarrollo materializecss y tengo inicializado los componentes del mismo.
- Estoy empleado VueJS para pintar los datos dinámicos en el front, para ello empleo Axios.
- Axios me devuelve un arreglo con un solo objeto, pero cuando quiero visualizarlo en el select no me lo muestra.

**Código HTML:**

```
<div class="input-field white-text">
        <i class="material-icons medium prefix">business</i>
             <select  v-model="selected" id="icon_prefix" class="white-text">   
                    <option value="" disabled seleceted>Seleccionar una Empresa</option>                                
                          <option 
                               placeholder="Seleccione una empresa"
                               v-for="(e,i) in empresas" 
                               :value="e.nombre" 
                               :key="i"
                           >
                               {{e.id}} - {{e.nombre}}
                           </option>
             </select> 
</div>
```

**Código VueJS:**

```
/* global axios */

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        selected: null,
        empresas: []
        
    },
     created() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/binapsweb/Empresas', {
            params: {op: 'get'}
        })
                .then(response => this.empresas = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log('Error: ' + error));
    }
});
```

En la siguiente imagen se puede ver que el arreglo de objetos me carga pero no se muestra al hacer clic en el select:

[image: Aca se puede observar como me muestra el arreglo de objetos con el dato que quiero mostrar en el select]

Sin embargo cuando en el modelo data la propiedad "Empresas" de la instancia Vue, la lleno con datos crudos que no viene de la petición hecha por axios, si me muestra los objetos en el select.

La pregunta es: ¿Qué puede estar pasando? cuando cargo la propiedad "Empresas" con la petición hecha en axios, no se muestra en el select; pero cuando tengo esta propiedad cargada con datos crudos si se muestra. Cuando digo datos crudos me refiero que en la instancia Vue en el modelo data tengo:

```
empresas: [
  { "id": "01", "nombre": "COPROCENVA" },
  { "id": "02", "nombre": "02COPROCENVA" },
  { "id": "03", "nombre": "03COPROCENVA" } ]
```

Agradezco de ante mano la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: En principio eso debería funcionar, ¿estás haciendo algo más en alguna otra parte que consideres que pueda estar afectando esto?

Comment: No, no hay nada en otra parte que pueda afectar. Pensé que podría ser la inicialización de los componentes de Materializecss pero si fuese esto, no tendría porque funcionar con el código crudo.